# Intuitive explanation of why equicontinuous sets are finite-dimensionally equiapproximable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces

I came across a rather clean general result from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273117/compact-subspace-of-a-banach-space), which states that:

*A subset $K$ of a Banach space $E$ is compact if and only if it is closed, bounded and satisfies the following condition: for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite-dimensional subspace $V\subset E$ such that $d(x,V)<\varepsilon$ for all $x \in K$.*

On the other hand, in the case when $E=C[0,1]$, the Arzela-Ascoli theorem characterizes compact subsets as those which are closed, bounded, and equicontinuous.

I would like to better understand the connection between equicontinuity and the "equiapproximability" condition in the first result. More precisely:

**Question:** Is there a conceptual proof that a closed bounded subset $K\subseteq C[0,1]$ is equicontinuous if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a finite-dimensional subspace $V$ such that $d(x,V)<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in K$?

Clearly one can piece together formal proofs of this fact, but I would like to gain some intuitive understanding of it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help. Suppose $K$ is bounded and equi-continuous. Let $\sup \{\|f\|: f\in K\}\le M\in\Bbb R^+.$ For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $A(n)=\{j/n: j\in \Bbb Z\land 0\le j\le n\}$ and $B(n)=\{Mk/n: k\in \Bbb Z\land |k|\le n\}.$

Consider the finite set $G_n$  of all $g\in C[0,1]$ such that $(i)$ if $x\in A(n)$ then $g(x)\in B(n),$ and $(ii)$ $g(x)$ is linear for $x\in [j/n,(j+1)/n]$ whenever $j/n$ and $(j+1)/n$ belong to $A(n).$

Now any $f\in C[0,1]$ with $\|f\|\le M$ can be uniformly approximated as closely as desired by some member of $G_n$ if $n$ is large enough.

The idea is that since $K$ is an equi-continuous family,  some sufficiently large $n$ will work for all $f\in K.$

Thus, if $n$ is large enough and $\varepsilon >0$, then for each $f\in K$ there exists $g\in G_n$ with  $\|f-g\|\le\varepsilon.$ Since $G_n$ is finite we can let $V$ be the vector subspace generated by $G_n.$